# How can I reorganize App Launcher icons on a Google Apps Account?

Tags: google-workspace, google-launcher

Google recently [added the option to drag icons](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/1714464) in the App launcher as shown in the animation below:

[image: Reorganizing apps]

I've done that on my normal Google account, but I am unable to drag around apps in my Google Apps account. When I drag an app, it simply acts like a dragged image.

Is there currently a way to customize the apps in my App launcher?

Answer (score 1):

I found that this only works when using a @gmail.com account, not when using Google Apps. Don't know why.

But if you are using the Chrome browser, there is an extension that will do this: [App Launcher Customizer for Google](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/applauncher?hl=en-US.).

Comment: This is no longer true. You can now drag around the icons in the App launcher for both Google Apps (enterprise) and Gmail (consumer) accounts. As is often the case, Google just takes longer rolling out changes to their enterprise customers then they do their consumer customers.